# Arduino and A4988

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new in the Arduino area.
What is necessary to control motors through Arduinos.

1. What is the difference between [A4988](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Motor-Driver-And-Interface-ICs/Bipolar-Stepper-Motor-Drivers/A4988.aspx) and the Arduino motor shield?
2. Is one A4988 needed for each stepper motor?
3. Or is one A4988 enough for all motors?

Answer (score 1):

An A4988 can control a single motor and supply up to 35V at 1.5A.
An Arduino motor shield can drive 2 DC Motors or 1 stepper motor at up to 12V and 4A/2A.

An A4988 needs mounting.
A motor shield drops straight in.

There are other options, including getting the ICs and doing it your self.  I have a motor shield which drives 4 DC motors or 2 Stepper motors that I got off eBay.

Answer (score 1):

The A4988 is a bipolar stepper driver. It is designed specifically to drive a single bipolar (4-wire) stepper motor. It consists of a pair of H-bridges and some extra drive logic to provide a simple GPIO interface.

The motor shield, in contrast, uses the L298D motor driver chip. This provides, as well, two H-bridges like the A4988. However it just gives you direct control of those H-bridges without a simple stepper-oriented interface.  So it is up to you to provide the correct control signals to effectively emulate the A4988's outputs.

Both chips can interface with exactly one bipolar stepper motor. The A4988 can *only* interface with a stepper motor. The L298D can *also* be used with other types of motor (though of course not at the same time as a bipolar stepper).

Comment: The L298 may seem more versatile, but it's also an antiquated high-loss bipolar device, vs a relatively modern and efficient FET one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed. But then people around here still use the LM741 and the TIP120, so the L298 isn't that bad by comparison ;)

Comment: @Majenko Are you absolutely certain the A4988 can't be used as an H-bridge for any type of motor?

Comment: @user2497 There's nothing to say you couldn't any other load up to it - however the interface to it is geared towards stepping. You don't have control over the H-bridge directly, you can only send it instructions on how to step a stepper motor and the internal logic controls the H-bridge for you. You have pins to set how far to step (1/1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 or 1/16 step), one for the direction, and one to initiate a step.  So yes, you could connect some other motor up to it, but you wouldn't be able to do anything useful with it.